# How can i split df row based on containing semicolon ;

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my DataFrame having 2 values in one row separated by semicolon ;

every row (containing 2 values separated by semicolon  ;  )

How can I split the value after ; to the next column (where two values will by side by side in two columns)?

### Heading ## needed output:

First row value (before ;) in the first column and
2nd value (after ;) into the next right column cell

[sample of edit needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNjpE.jpg)

[sample of my dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqUgh.jpg)

i found that code which split row values into multiple rows (separated by ,)

```
explode(df.assign(var1=df.var1.str.split(',')), 'var1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use `Pandas.str.split()` method:

`split_vals = df['col_to_split'].str.split(";", expand = True)`

This will produce a new Data frame, `split_vals` that contains two columns, one containing all the string before the ";", and another for the remainder of the string. You can then assign these new columns to your original df:

`df['before'] = split_vals[0]`

`df['after'] = split_vals[1]`

Comment: No problem :) can you accept my answer (the green tick if you're new to this)